# How to disable postfix/mail/mailqueue on my server?

Tags: linux, email, debian, postfix

I'm running a debian squeeze server. I've been having problems with certain websites sending spam, so I've disabled postfix completely (`/etc/init.d/postfix stop`).

However, the sites trying to send spam are still queueing the mail, which I can see with the `mailq` command.

How can I disable this too? I don't want anything to be able to send/queue any (postfix) mail. However, I still want the server to be able to store its errors to /var/mail/root as it normally does.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered changing postfix's sendmail program permissions?

You may create can-send-mail group and allow only root (owner) and the group to execute sendmail program.